Align y axis labels
I am creating three seperate plots which I then combine using patchwork. The third plot that I make uses facet_grid in order to add a secondary x axis with the years showing. But I think this somehow messes with the alignment of my y-axis labels.
For this third graph, the y axis labels are now connected to the graph with no space inbetween, like in the first two.
#First graph
 presence <- ggplot(df_long, aes(x = date)) +
 geom_bar(aes(y = total_presence, fill = "Presence"), stat = "identity", width = 1, position = "stack") +
 geom_bar(aes(y = total_song, fill = "Song"), stat = "identity", width = 1, position = "stack") +
 geom_bar(data = filter(df_long, is.na(total_presence) & is.na(total_song)),
 aes(x=date, y =24), fill = "azure3", stat="identity", width = 1, position = "stack") +
 scale_fill_manual(values = c("Presence" = "olivedrab", "Song" = "olivedrab3"), name = "Detections") +
 scale_y_continuous(name = "Presence", breaks = seq(0,24,by=2), limits = c(0,24),expand=c(0,0))+
 scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b", date_breaks="1 month", expand= c(0,0))+
 labs(x=NULL, y = "Total Detections", title = paste(location)) +
 theme_minimal() +
 theme(axis.title.y = element_text(color = "black"),
 axis.text.y = element_text(color = "black"),
 axis.ticks.y=element_line(color="black"),
 panel.grid = element_blank(),
 legend.position = "right",
 plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
 
#Second graph
 ice_temp <- ggplot(df_long, aes(x=date)) +
 geom_bar(aes(y=Proportion,fill=Ice_Type), stat = "identity", position = "stack", width = 1) +
 geom_line(aes(y = (sst_mean/4)+0.5), color = "red", size = 0.4) +
       #labs(x=NULL, y="Sea Ice Proportion", title = paste("Daily Sea Ice Cover and SST at", location, year_start, "-", year_end))+
 labs(x=NULL, y="Sea Ice Proportion", title = NULL)+
 scale_fill_manual(values = c(
         "VeryOpenDriftIce" = "#7FDBFF",
         "OpenDriftIce" = "#0074D9",
         "CloseDriftIce" = "#00457e",
         "VeryCloseDriftIce" = "#001f3f",
         "FastIce" = "red"
       )) +
 theme_minimal() +
 scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, NA), expand=c(0,0),
 sec.axis = sec_axis(~ (.-0.5)*4, name = "Sea Surface Temperature (°C)",
 breaks = seq(-2,2,by=1)))+
 scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b", date_breaks="1 month", expand= c(0,0))+
 theme(panel.grid = element_blank(), legend.position = "right",
 axis.ticks = element_line(),
 axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = "red"),
 axis.text.y.right = element_text(color = "red"),
 axis.ticks.y.right=element_line(color="red"))
  
 #third graph
 zooc_chl <- ggplot(df_long, aes(x=date)) +
 geom_line(aes(y=zooc_mean),color="#D55E00", size = 0.4) +
 geom_line(aes(y=chl_mean),color="#0072B2",size=0.4)+
       #labs(x=NULL, y="<span style = 'color:#D55E00;'>Zooplankton [g/m<sup>2</sup>]</span>  \n<span style = 'color:#0072B2;'>Chlorophyll a [mg/m<sup>3</sup>]</span>", title = paste("Primary Production, Zooplankton and Chlorophyll a at", location, year_start, "-", year_end))+
 labs(x=NULL, y="<span style = 'color:#D55E00;'>Zooplankton [g/m<sup>2</sup>]</span>  \n<span style = 'color:#0072B2;'>Chlorophyll a [mg/m<sup>3</sup>]</span>", title = NULL)+
 scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,3,by=0.5), limits = c(0,3),expand=c(0,0))+
 scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b", date_breaks="1 month", expand= c(0,0))+
 facet_grid(~ year(date), space= "free", scales="free",switch="x") +
 theme_minimal() +
 theme(axis.title.y=element_markdown(),
 strip.placement = "outside",
 axis.ticks = element_line(),
 strip.background = element_rect(fill=NA,colour="grey50"),
 panel.spacing=unit(0,"cm"))
 
 #combine graphs
 combined_plot <- presence / ice_temp / zooc_chl


I tried fixing this with margins or vjust/hjust but havent been able to fix it.
Does anyone know what I can do to align the y axis labels?

Do you have sample data? It'd be easier if we had something to base the code off of. Thanks!

It's better if you can provide a minimal reproducible example including a small amount of data.
Using minimal made-up data, and by stripping away code to just that which causes the issue, it looks like theme(strip.placement = "outside") is the cause. See the aligned and misaligned versions below:
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)

df <-
  tibble(
    date = seq(ymd("2024-01-01"), length.out = 100, by = "day"),
    y = rnorm(100, 1, 10)
  )

p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(date)) +
  geom_bar()

p2 <- ggplot(df, aes(date)) +
  geom_bar()

p3 <- ggplot(df, aes(date, y)) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(x = NULL, y = "some text", title = "Aligned") +
  facet_grid(~ year(date), space = "free", scales = "free", switch = "x")

# Aligned
p1 / p2 / p3



# Misaligned
p4 <- p3 + theme(strip.placement = "outside") + ggtitle("Misaligned")

p1 / p2 / p4


Created on 2024-04-10 with reprex v2.1.0
